# add active class to owl-item in owl carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel as a thumbnail viewer and trying to add an active class to "owl-item". I Have tried afterAction and afterInit as per the owl carousel docs, both add an active class to the first item but none of the others when selected.

```
owldemo.owlCarousel({
items : 4,
responsive:false,
pagination: false,
navigation: true,
afterAction: function(el){
//afterinit: function(el)//same results

   this
   .$owlItems
   .removeClass('active')

   this
   .$owlItems 
   .eq(this.currentItem)
   .addClass('active')

 }
 });
```

Comment: I can't give an answer without complete HTML code which reproduces the problem. Have you seen this demo? http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/click.html

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/OwlFonk/pen/dnEga/

```
<button id="btn">Check Current Item</button>
```

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){

  var active = carousel.find(".owl-item.active");

  alert(active.text())

})
```